# Monitor Not Detected by Computer

Tags: multiple-monitors

Last night I unplugged my wireless USB headset receiver from my computer, and one of my monitors disconnected and will not reconnect. So far I've done some troubleshooting including:

- Restarting my computer.
- Using a different port on my graphics card. They are all confirmed working with two different monitors.
- Using a different input on the monitor.
- Switching out all cables/adapters. Again confirmed working with the same two different monitors.
- Testing the monitor with a different computer. It is confirmed working.
- On Windows 10, going to the device manager in the control panel and uninstalling/reinstalling my graphics card.
- Power cycling the monitor.
- Updating drivers.
- Switching to Linux Mint 19.3. Still no picture.
- Using a fourth monitor. My computer did not detect this one.

After doing all of the above my computer will not detect the monitor and I am at a loss of what to do next. For reference I am using an Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti with driver 26.21.14.4587, and the port I was using for the receiver was on an internal PCIE add-in card. My graphics card has 3 display port ports and one HDMI and I was using a generic HDMI to display port adapter for the monitor.

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the hardware links have been tested independently, and you can't find/enable it in the display manager's `Display` settings, maybe X has done something funky to the config relationship. Does it show the monitor connected with a mode set when you run `xrandr`?

You could try

```
xrandr --output [port_name] --auto --brightness 1
```

Which should turn it on if it's just been `--off`ed somehow, and make sure brightness is up. If it shows up, lists modes, but doesn't have one starred, you might have to do `xrandr --output [port] --mode [resolution]`

or `xset -dpms` to turn off any power management stuff that could be strange on this hardware

Also check your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, and `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` for anything strange.

I think I also once had a problem where I've had to re-add the xrandr mode entirely to make a monitor work, there's a guide to doing that [here](https://medium.com/devsys/adding-a-new-display-resolution-in-linux-ba08d73f327) if you want to try it, but usually adding a mode to a port listing none is usually only used for making virtual screens.

But to be honest none of that shouldn't be fixed by switching distro, unless it's being caused by a config file or partition you're keeping between them

Have you tried running a graphical session as the root user, seeing if that makes a difference?

good luck!

Comment: For reference I primarily use Windows 10 and have used Linux for about a month, but I'm working through that guide you linked to try and get the monitor detected in Linux. I got to the "addmode" step and got a `BadMatch` error, and I'm still working to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bad HDMI cable. I should have been more thorough in my basic troubleshooting.